# How do I return an error from route in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to return an error to the user whenever he sends invalid data to the server, eg. 8 digits instead of 10 in a phone number input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the current node.js process by calling `process.exit(1)`
See [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code).

**EDIT:**
If you want to keep the server running but simply return an error message from the route you can do something like this:

`return res.status(400).send('Mobile number must be 10 digits long');`

This sends HTTP code '400 Bad request' to the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it. :-)

Comment: @VishalPrajapati great, hope this helps!

Comment: But I stop execution of script I.e. can't serve request anymore but I want that it will work and listen to user request. I.e. just prevent execution of rest of code for that particular request.

Comment: @VishalPrajapati I see, I must have misunderstood your question. I've edited my answer with a fix proposal. By the way it would help a lot if you would paste in your code block so I can understand your problem better.